# I'm trying to output my scrapy results to a csv file, but my output is always blank

Tags: python, csv, cmd, scrapy

Here is my main spider bathuni.py

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from bathUni.items import BathuniItem

class bathuni(Spider):
    name = "bathU"
    allowed_domains = ["http://international.southwales.ac.uk/"]
    start_urls= ["http://international.southwales.ac.uk/country/argentina/en/",
                 "http://international.southwales.ac.uk/country/france/en/",
                 "http://international.southwales.ac.uk/country/australia/en/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="factsheet"]/ul/li')
        for site in sites:
            country = site.xpath('text()').extract()
            return country
```

My items.py is as follows

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class BathuniItem(Item):
    Country = Field()
```

and the command I'm using to output into a csv file is

```
scrapy crawl bathU -o countries.csv -t csv
```

My output file is always empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `return country` to `yield BathuniItem(Country=country)`

this solves two issues:

1. `ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'unicode'`
2. use yield to return a python generator - multiple items from a function

Comment: Great thanks, that did exactly what I wanted it to do. I'm wondering if it's possible you could tell me how to be more specific when scraping data rather than just /ul/li/ I don't want all of the /ul/li on the web pages just some specific ones, is there a way of scraping them via their css?

Comment: your xpath seem to use the div class, so I guess you are aware of the power of xpath, try to google for some more xpath examples, its a very powerful tool

Comment: Wow, this has opened up so many doors for me and my project, thanks a lot.